# Updating session using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want the session to be updated whenever an element is clicked in the div, but it looks like my session is not updating whenever I use an ajax. I want the session to be updated, not just printing the data in my ajax.

here is my ajax:

```
$('.chat_div').click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'plugins/get_id.php',
        data: {id:id},
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['chat_mate_id'];?>");
        }
    });
    });
```

here is my php file:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['chat_mate_id'] = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: First thing you are doing it very wrong.. you just can't expected session varaible in ajax response.. after setting it on ajax call.. because your page is already loaded.. and session variable is already printed into the as alert message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are generating an HTML document, which has some embedded JS in it. At the time you generate the HTML document, you output the value of a session variable into the JS as a *string literal*.

Next, you run the JS, which makes a second HTTP request, and updates the value of the session variable.

When the response arrives, you alert the value of the string you injected into the page **when the original page loaded**.

If you want to react to the *new* value of the session variable, then you have to use data that you get from the server **after** you update the value.

The **output** of running a PHP program a minute ago will not change retroactively. Ajax is not time travel.